# Why HttpRequest callbacks not working without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, temenos-quantum

I have a issue in getting response in Kony application. this is the code

```
function getServerResponceOption(url){
        alert(url);
        var httpclient2 = new kony.net.HttpRequest();
        var requestMethod = constants.HTTP_METHOD_GET;
        var async = true;
        httpclient2.open(requestMethod, url,async);
        if(getAccessToken() != null && getAccessToken() != ""){
        httpclient2.setRequestHeader("AuthToken",getAccessToken());
        }
        httpclient2.send();
        httpclient2.onReadyStateChange = HandleResponce(httpclient2);   
}

function HandleResponce(obj)
{
   alert("Getting data "+obj.readyState+"   Status "+obj.status+" Response "+obj.response );
    if(obj.readyState == 4 )
    {
        if (obj.response != null && obj.response != "")
            {
                 var jsonObj = obj.response;
                 handleResponseOption(0,jsonObj);
                 return;
            }
            else
            {

            }
    }else{
     var state = obj.status;
     alert("Readystate "+obj.readyState+"  Status = "+state);
    }

    if (obj.response != null && obj.response != "")
     {
        var jsonObj = obj.response;
        handleResponseOption(1,jsonObj);
     }
}
```

Here i got server response if i put the alert message in `HandleResponce(obj)` without the alert i didn't get any response. the ready state is 1 and status is 0. What is the problem occurred if i remove the alert message?

Note: URL and getAccessToken() is getting values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling function in line, When you use `HandleResponce(httpclient2)` function is immediately executed.

```
httpclient2.onReadyStateChange = HandleResponce(httpclient2);
```

Change your code as

```
httpclient2.onReadyStateChange = function(){ HandleResponce(httpclient2) };
```